# How to hide a div only on mobiles(large screen always has to be displayed) based on a content using Angularjs or css

Tags: css, angularjs

hide a div only on mobiles(large screen always has to be displayed) based on a content using Angularjs or css

Comment: What do you mean with based on a content?

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 480px)` don' solve your problem?

Comment: No it didn't solved my problem. Based on content means I get the value from the model i.e Boolean value whether to show\hide the div on  mobile device

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2000px to 480px or other value, it depents of you

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2000px){
  .box{
    display: none;
  }
  input:checked + .box{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, if you want to style the checkbox, just put it inside a `label` tag, hide the input, and stylize the label, with an image or just css

Comment: My page has more than one check box so it is not setting properly

Comment: you just need to add an Id or a class to the element, they must be side by side

Answer (score 0):

Add class = "divclass" to your html then in your css file:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .divclass{
     display: none;
  }
}
```